# Testing functions using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to test a angular code using protractor. I am able to test the elements which are visible on html using element(by.id or by.css). I need a way to test the functions which are in the javascript file. Suppose when we click on a button on html that calls a function in javascript file which is what I want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a scoping problem here. With `protractor`, you test your application from one end to another from an end-user perspective through the user interface opened in your browser by automating user actions - clicking, entering keys, hovering etc.

To test a function, you should look into [AngularJS unit-testing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing).

Comment: thank you!! that was what I was looking for..May I know if Karma can be used to test modules?

Comment: @user3633315 karma is a test runner which is, yes, usually used to run unit tests. Glad it helps.

Comment: I am trying to do unit testing using jasmine framework. Does that work or do we need karma along with that.

Comment: @user3633315 `jasmine` is a testing framework, `karma` is a test runner - you need both.

Comment: .service('sampleSvc', function($http, $q, $window, modalSvc){   I have a service like this.. Do I have to inject $http $q $window modalSvc as dependencies while I am doing unit testing? I am always getting an error like this Unknown Provider: modalSvcprovider<--modalSvc<--sampleSvc ..

Comment: @user3633315 let's avoid solving follow-up problems in comments. Consider creating a separate SO question if you have difficulties - this way much more people can help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I did add another questions. Thank you.